# Android JSON parse this, how?

Tags: android, json

```
 [
    {
        "hotelid": [
            {
                "hotelid": "1",
                "name": "aaa",
                "code": "111",
                "price": "111"
            },            
            {
                "hotelid": "2",
                "name": "bbb",
                "code": "112",
                "price": "211"
            },
            {
                "hotelid": "4",
                "name": "ccc",
                "code": "42",
                "price": "411"
            }

...
```

I have this JSON, how can I parse it in android? I tried it, but i only get errors.

code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mycontext=this;

    examineJSONFile();
}

class Result
{
  List<Hotel> hotel; // name matches name in JSON

  @Override
  public String toString() {return hotel.toString();}
}


class Hotel
{
  String code;          // name matches name in JSON
  String name;          // name matches name in JSON
  String hotelid;       // name matches name in JSON

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("hotelid:{code=%s, name=%s, hotelid=%s}", code, name, hotelid);  
  }
}


void examineJSONFile()    {

    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.promo);
    String s;
    try {
        s = HttpConnect.streamToString(is);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY));

        Result[] results = mapper.readValue(s, Result[].class);
        Result result = results[0];

        Log.e("res", result.toString()+"");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("err", e+"");
    }


}
```

> ERROR/err(23124): org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can
>   not deserialize Class com.android.asd.asdStart$Result (of type
>   non-static member class) as a Bean

Comment: "I tried it, but i only get errors." Then you should post code and ask for help with the errors.  As it stands, this question falls into the category of "gimme teh codez."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried to parse that JSON string and I got one solution please try this also:

```
String parse = "[{\"hotelid\":[{\"hotelid\":\"1\",\"name\":\"aaa\",\"code\":\"111\",\"price\":\"111\"},{\"hotelid\":\"2\",\"name\":\"bbb\",\"code\":\"112\",\"price\":\"211\"},{\"hotelid\":\"4\",\"name\":\"ccc\",\"code\":\"42\",\"price\":\"411\"}]}]";
            try {
                JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(parse);
                for(int i=0;i<menuObject.length();i++){
                    String hotel =    menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("hotelid").toString();
                    System.out.println("hotel="+hotel);
                    JSONArray menuObject1 = new JSONArray(hotel);
                    for(int j=0; j<menuObject1.length();j++){
                        String hotelid =    menuObject1.getJSONObject(j).getString("hotelid").toString();
                        System.out.println("hotelid=="+hotelid);

                        String name =    menuObject1.getJSONObject(j).getString("name").toString();
                        System.out.println("name=="+name);

                        String code =    menuObject1.getJSONObject(j).getString("code").toString();
                        System.out.println("code=="+code);

                        String price =    menuObject1.getJSONObject(j).getString("price").toString();
                        System.out.println("price=="+price);

                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is asked so many times.

Use `com.google.gson` package. it is 99% similar to `org.json` package (json.jar).

- [How to Parse a JSON Object In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566669/how-to-parse-a-json-object-in-android)
- [Parse JSON data into Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228033/parse-json-data-into-android-listview)
- [how to parse this json obj android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040154/how-to-parse-this-json-obj-android)
- [JSON and ANDROID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310119/json-and-android)
- [How can I parse this JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605077/how-can-i-parse-this-json-in-android)

You should Google it next time.

Comment: how come accepted answer work? your code is not related to JSON. you are using some other 3rd party JSON library. -1 for bad question.

Answer (score 3):

Following is an example using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) as the Java-to/from-JSON library.  Jackson is one of the fast, most feature-rich Java/JSON APIs available.

I made a guess at what the actual target JSON structure is.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    // input:
    // [
    //   {
    //     "hotel": [
    //       {"id":"52472","name":"africa","hotel":"asd"},
    //       {"id":"52471","name":"europe","hotel":"asd2"},
    //       {"id":"52470","name":"europe","hotel":"asd3"}
    //     ]
    //   }
    // ]
    String input = "[{\"hotel\":[{\"id\":\"52472\",\"name\":\"africa\",\"hotel\":\"asd\"},{\"id\":\"52471\",\"name\":\"europe\",\"hotel\":\"asd2\"},{\"id\":\"52470\",\"name\":\"europe\",\"hotel\":\"asd3\"}]}]";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // configure Jackson to access non-public fields
    mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY));

    Result[] results = mapper.readValue(input, Result[].class);
    Result result = results[0];
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}

class Result
{
  List<Hotel> hotel; // name matches name in JSON

  @Override
  public String toString() {return hotel.toString();}
}

class Hotel
{
  String id; // name matches name in JSON
  String name; // name matches name in JSON
  String hotel; // name matches name in JSON

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("Hotel:{id=%s, name=%s, hotel=%s}", id, name, hotel);  
  }
}
```

Comment: 07-13 10:06:33.008: ERROR/err(23124): org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize Class com.android.asd.asdStart$Result (of type non-static member class) as a Bean

Comment: It looks like you copied the code differently than I provided it.  It looks like you made something an inner class of something else.  The code I posted doesn't have any inner class definitions.  If you're still stuck, post the entire code necessary to replicate the problem.

Comment: in your case you should make classes Result and Hotel static, because you move them into Activity class

Comment: yeah u are right. new errors: 07-13 16:38:59.676: ERROR/err(504): org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "hotelid" (Class com.android.asd.asdStart$Result), not marked as ignorable

Answer (score 3):

Make class Result and Hotel static. Parser can't create instance of inner class which is not static

Answer (score 2):

This JSON is invalid. You miss closing ] bracket. You can check your JSON [here](http://jsonlint.com/)